# How to Terraform assignment of Azure User Managed Identity to a storage account?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to grant an Azure 'User Assigned Managed Identity' permissions to an Azure storage account via Terraform.

I'm struggling to find the best way to do this - any ideas would be much appreciated!

Background: I'm looking to deploy HDInsights and point it at a Data Lake Gen2 storage account. For the HDInsights deployment to succeed it needs to reference a Managed Identity that has 'Storage Blob Data Owner' permissions to the storage account.

I can successfully create the storage account and Managed Identity via Terraform. However, I'm stuck on the best way to assign the Managed Identity to the storage account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Managed Identity, it essentially creates a service principal in your tenant. So you could use [azurerm_role_assignment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html)  to assign the service principal as a `Storage Blob Data Owner` role to the storage account.

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

data "azurerm_client_config" "test" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "test" {
  scope                = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = "${data.azurerm_client_config.test.service_principal_object_id}"
}
```

The sample assigns the role at the subscription scope, for your case, just change the `scope` to the storage account, `role_definition_name` to `Storage Blob Data Owner`,  the `principal_id` is the `Object ID` of your Managed Identity(service principal).

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for thanks. It hadn't clicked that **azurerm_role_assignment** can also be used for Managed Identities. I was able to successfully use this to assign the `Storage Blob Data Owner` to the storage account.

Comment: @AndrewKelleher how do you get the ID of the managed identity for the role assignment?

Comment: for storage account role assignment , scope should be resource_id - There was a bug reported as Id does not work for it.  see here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/6170